# How to get all objects with their children using django orm?

Tags: django, django-models, tree

I got very simple hierarchical structure: every object can have 0 or 1 parent. There's no limit on how many children each object can have.

So in my application I got such a model:

```
class O(Model):
  name = CharField(max_length = 20)
  parent = ForeignKey('O', related_name = 'children')
```

Now I would like to be able to fetch all objects who have a particular one `Object1` in their parent-tree (as in their parent or parent of their parents, etc).

Should I use [mptt](http://code.google.com/p/django-mptt/) or is there a simpler approach?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I suggest to use [mppt](http://code.google.com/p/django-mptt/). I like it.

There are a lot of usefull functions like instance.get_ancestors() or instance.get_children().
And many good and usfull template tags.

Answer (score 0):

if you go with [mptt](http://code.google.com/p/django-mptt/) I suggest reading the [docs](http://django-mptt.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/) first. It's a nice implementation, and it's going to be the easiest in this case.

What you are looking for is named get_descendants() in mptt.

Be careful and use svn trunk, since the last release is not compatible with Django 1.0 and onwards. Hope this helps.